# Make border clip other elements and show background content

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create a spinner where two dots intersect and the foremost one should clip the other letting the background be visible on few pixels of intersection.

[image]

It would be okay to use SVG if CSS isn't capable of this, but at the moment I can't find a way to achieve the effect in neither of the technologies.

I tried with `clip-path` but it doesn't seem to do what am I trying to do.

Ideas?

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0%, purple 100%);
}

.a, .b {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  left: 50vw;
  border: 4px solid white;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do in SVG.  However you'll want to use a `<mask>` rather than a `<clipPath>`.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 0%, purple 100%);
}

svg {
  margin: 5em 0 0 50vw;
}
```

```html
<svg width="80" height="50">
  <defs>
    <mask id="clipred">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle cx="55" cy="25" r="29" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="red" mask="url(#clipred)"/>
  <circle cx="55" cy="25" r="25" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```